# Prevent Checkobx from User action WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, checkbox

I have a application which shows an user and the attributes of an user.
I am showing the attribute "is Admin" in a checkbox s0 if he is an admin then the chebox is checked and if not then it isnt.

This is my XAML code

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding LoadedUser.IsAdmin, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="5,7,0,0"/>
```

As it should only show if the user is admin or not you shouldnt be able to check or uncheck the Checkbox.
Is there any possibility to "block" or "protect" the Checkbox from clicks by the user ?

Comment: Why can anyone click this at all?  Would it not be better to have some sort of little icon or text indicating the user is an admin?

Comment: Yeah I think Ill change it later to an icon or somethin like that. I am just writing the first sketch to check functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `IsHitTestVisible="False"` or do bind this property to the model:

```
<CheckBox IsHitTestVisible="False" IsChecked="{Binding LoadedUser.IsAdmin, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="5,7,0,0"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the IsEnabled Property to enable/disable the checkbox depending on  whether the current user is Admin or not.
For example,

```
<CheckBox IsEnabled="{Binding CurrentUser.IsAdmin}" IsChecked="{Binding LoadedUser.IsAdmin, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="5,7,0,0"/>
```

The disabled state conveys to non-admin users that they cannot access it

Comment: Right now your suggestion wouldnt work as I  do not have an Property whick checks if the current user is an Admin. Maybe you got my question above wrong. But thanks for your Answer

Comment: May be i understood the question wrong, So if you do not have something which decides whether to enable or disable this property, what could be the usecase when you actually enable it ? If it was supposed to be always false, then do you really need a checkbox ?

Comment: So the whole Application is a user management. An Admin can show details of an user and one attribute of those details is to show if the selected user is an admin or not.